# GraphQL Codegen – How to make Partial the return type of a resolver partial but keep the arguments required?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, graphql-codegen

I am using this configuration file:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: "src/**/*.(resolver|type).ts"
documents: null
generates:
  src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-resolvers"
    config:
      typesSuffix: GQL
      resolverTypeSuffix: Resolver
```

Works fine but it's really annoying to cast `as any as TypeGQL` every time I want to delegate a property of the returned object to another resolver.

Here I have to forcefully cast `as any` because it's missing the field `regions` which I want to delegate to it's own resolver.

```js
export const CountryResolver: CountryResolverGQL<GQLContext> = {
  async regions(parent, _args, { dataSources }) {
    const regions = await dataSources.placesService.getRegionsFromCountryId(parent.id!)
    return regions.map((region) => ({ ...region, country: parent } as any))
  }
}
```

I've also tried adding the option:

```yaml
config:
  defaultMapper: Partial<{T}>
```

But that also modifies the parameters of my resolvers to be `Partial<Parent>` or something like that.

And I am forced of changing code that was fine to:

```js
export const CountryResolver: CountryResolverGQL<GQLContext> = {
  async regions(parent, _args, { dataSources }) {
    const regions = await dataSources.placesService.getRegionsFromCountryId(parent.id!)
    return regions.map((region) => ({ ...region, country: parent as CountryGQL }))
  }
}
```

How do I go about making *only* the return type of the resolver Partial?

Comment: Any luck on this? Looking to accomplish something like this as well

Comment: No. We finished the project with the undesired partials and moved on with life :(. Still looking for an answer :)

Comment: Found this because searching a solution for this very problem. Nice to see that it's not just me.